# How to test my solana program code by rust on beta.solpg.io?

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, blockhash

I have a rust solana program code on beta.solpg.io.

After development, I am about to test my code but I don't know how to do it.

I copied deposit and withdraw program sample code on github, but I don't know how it works and tests.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to write tests yourself first in the `anchor.test.ts` file under `tests` folder: [image: Screenshot]

Then, you can either run `test` command in CLI or click on the "
Test" button. In case you don't see the file there, just create a anchor.test.ts yourself and get started!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
It is so helpful but can you please let me know more in detail ?
If possible, can you please share your sample code and how to use it ?
Actually, I am newbie on blockchain.
I don't know the way I can learn solana smart contract step by step.
I prefer doc tutorials to video tutorial.
If possible please let me know how to learn it in a short term.
I have basic knowledge about JS,PHP,C# and Python.
Thanks.
I am waiting for your rely.